# Is it possible to bypass the frp lock by installing another ROM

Tags: android, passwords, adb

I have an samsung a40 that my sister gave me. She forgot the password of the phone. I factory reseted it with the recovery mode and now there is the FRP lock but i dont have acces to the google account.

The question is: is it possible to install another os on the phone with the recoverymode to bypass the FRP lock.

I tried to turn on the USB debugging with the recovery menu but it did not work